# Does it make a difference if I use a default initalisation or no initialisation?

Tags: java

Are there any cases that using a default initialization such as:

```
int myValue;
```

or

```
MyObject o = null;
```

could change the behaviour of my program compare to cases where I don't initialize the variables at all?

I'm looking for an example.

Comment: Assuming that you're talking about class fields: No. Example of what?

Comment: I'm talking about class fields and local variables. An example where this could change the program behaviour, (if there is any)

Answer (score 8):

Local variables must be initialized before being used. That is enforced by the compiler.

Fields are initialized by default to the default value associated with their type (false, 0, null). That's required by the Java Language Specification.

So initializing them explicitely to their default value just adds noise, most of the time:

```
MyObject o = null;
```

doesn't do anything more than

```
MyObject o;
```

Comment: The byte code generated by `int val = 0;` as a field is a different length to `int val;` as a field so it seems there might be some differences.

Comment: There is a difference in the bytecode, but it doesn't change anything semantically. Just like doing `a = 1; a = 1; a = 1;` is equivalent to doing `a = 1;`.

Comment: Sure there is a difference, it's minor and slightly contrived but very real - see my example, in particular the disassembly of the byte code. (I hadn't looked at it when I posted that comment).

Answer (score 3):

Yes there can be a difference, as in this example. It's a little contrived but it comes down to the time at which the initialization occurs.

Consider the following class:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class base {
  protected base(int arg) throws Exception {
    Field f = getClass().getDeclaredField("val");
    System.out.println(f.get(this));
    f.set(this, 666);
  }
}
```

And the following two classes which extend it. `test1` explicitly sets to 0:

```
public class test1 extends base {
  int val=0; // Explicitly set to 0

  public test1() throws Exception {
    super(0);
  }

  public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(new test1().val);
  }
}
```

`test2` just leaves it:

```
public class test2 extends base {
  int val; // just leave it to be default

  public test2() throws Exception {
    super(0);
  }

  public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(new test2().val);
  }
}
```

Running these gives:

```
javac test1.java && java test1                        
0
0
```

But for the second case:

```
javac test2.java && java test2                        
0
666
```

This neatly illustrates a different behaviour and the only change is the `= 0` for the field.

The reason for this can be seen by disassembling the first case:

```
import java.io.PrintStream;

public synchronized class test1 extends base
{
    int val;

    public test1()
        throws Exception
    {
        super(0);
        val = 0; // Note that the the explicit '= 0' is after the super()
    }

    public static void main(String astring[])
        throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println(new test1().val);
    }
}
```

If this makes a difference in your code base you have bigger things to worry about though!

Comment: Also w/o reflection:

```
public class Main {
  abstract static class Base implements Runnable {
    protected Base() {
      run();
    }
  }
  static class DerivedExplicitDefault extends Base {
    int val = 0;
    public void run() {
      val = 666;
    }
  }
  static class DerivedImplicitDefault extends Base  {
    int val;
    public void run() {
      val = 666;
    }
  }
  public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(new DerivedExplicitDefault().val);
    System.out.println(new DerivedImplicitDefault().val);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java, the instance and static member fields of a class are assigned a default value : primitives default to 0, objects to null and boolean to false.

However, Java requires that you assign a value to local variables, which are declared within the scope of a method, before you can use them. There is NO default value for such variable.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding there is no such case. Java specification requires variables be initialized by default according to the following rules:

> numbers: 0 or 0.0
>   booleans: false
>   object references: null

As long as you program with these rules in mind, explicitly initializing to the same values as above will not change the behavior of the program.