# What is the difference between a variable assigned to null and others not assigned

Tags: java

what is the difference between a variable assigned to null and others not assigned in java.

I know that there is a difference in  the method's block , witch mean i can use the variable that has initialised to null but i can't use that isn't initialised

can you tell me why ?

edit:
Thanks to everyone who answered

My question is about the behavior and the form of references in the memory

Comment: The answer is in the question: one has an assigned value of `null`, the others don't have an assigned value at all.

Comment: check the [jls](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-16.html)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12461607/does-it-make-a-difference-if-i-use-a-default-initalisation-or-no-initialisation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What is the difference between a variable assigned to `null` and others not assigned?

- An uninitialized variable does not have a value, not even `null` (which is why it can't be read)
- An initialized variable does have a value (for instance `null`, `5` or `"hello"`).

Note that member variables get default values assigned to them automatically (and the default value for a reference type is `null`). So while it may seem like you can read an "uninitialized" member variable, the truth is that it *is* in fact initialized.

Answer (score 2):

Directely from [Oracle site](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Fields that are declared but not initialized will be set to a reasonable default by the compiler. Generally speaking, this default will be zero or null, depending on the data type. Relying on such default values, however, is generally considered bad programming style.

The following chart summarizes the default values for the above data types.

Data Type   Default Value (for fields)
byte    0
short   0
int 0
long    0L
float   0.0f
double  0.0d
char    '\u0000'
String (or any object)      null
boolean false

Local variables are slightly different; the compiler never assigns a default value to an uninitialized local variable. If you cannot initialize your local variable where it is declared, make sure to assign it a value before you attempt to use it. Accessing an uninitialized local variable will result in a compile-time error.

Hope helped you!

Answer (score 1):

It's explicit intent versus implication. If you don't set an object to *anything* you may have forgotten and thus the compiler reminds you. If you explicitly set to null, then the compiler is confident you made the choice. Also, for some types, the unset value could be something other than null, so allowing the compiler to make the choice is dangerous (c.f. C++ defaulting issues differing between implementations).

Answer (score 1):

Variables assigned to `null` means it is not pointing to anything where as the one which is not `assigned` and if it is a local variable means it is not even initialized yet

```
Test t1=null; ----> Not Pointing to any Object 
Test t2; ------> Not even initialized
```

if t2 is local variable and you will use it you'll get Compilation Error, as first initialize before use as default value is not there for this variable

Answer (score 1):

See the [JLS 4.12.5. Initial Values of Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5):

> For all reference types ([§4.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3)), the default value is `null`.

```
ReferenceType:
    ClassOrInterfaceType
    TypeVariable
    ArrayType
```

So there's no difference for *member variables*, if you don't explicitly assign it to `null`, it'll be implicitly assigned.